# Unwinding multiple ModalViewControllers using Unwind Segue

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, unwind-segue

I have a a project that displays multiple view controllers.

The `ViewController A` is the Root. `A` presents `B` using a Modal presentation. `B` presents `C` using a Modal presentation, and so on.

I have an Unwind segue that unwinds back to the root, however I noticed that it if I am on `ViewController` `D`, the unwinding behaviour is `D`->`C`->`B` -> `A(Root)`. Therefore you see `C` briefly, then `B` briefly, before `A` is shown. They seem to be getting dismissed one at a time. The desired effect is `D` straight back to `A`, with `B` and `C` remaining hidden. Is it possible to do this, maybe unwind segue is no the right way to go.

The unwind segue is in `UIViewController` `A`;

```
- (IBAction)unwindToRoot:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{

    NSLog(@"Root");
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591 refer to this document

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by

Embedding my initial VC in a Navigation Controller - hiding the navigation bar.  Changing the transitions to be push show transitions.  Then using a custom transition object that did the same animation I wanted (cross-disolve)

Based in part on http://objectivetoast.com/2014/03/17/custom-transitions-on-ios/

See example https://github.com/feralbob/ModalModalUnwind